# Compress large amount of data

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb, filesystems, compression

I have IP ADDRESSES in a table

```
0.0.0.1 Port 80;23 hash sha256 value
0.0.0.2 Port 110;443 hash sha256 value
0.0.0.3 Port 80;443 hash sha256 value
-
254.254.254.254 Port 443
```

all in all a large amount of data.
Right now if I was to create the database with all possible combinations, it would take 700 gig +

But there is a large amount of data that is redundant,  like the 0.0. I can save space on that. 
There are a few ways I have thought about this 
1: use windows servers data duplication to help shrink the file (by creating a container and sticking the file in the contaner) This would create limited overhead, and I don't know what would be better to use, Microsoft SQL on MongoDB, Please advise if anyone has used data duplication on mongodb or sql.

2: leave the 0.0.0. out of the database, meaning that the database would hold

```
.1
.2 
.3
.4
```

This way I know that my program would need to search

```
0.0.0.1 and 
1.1.1.1 , 
2.2.2.1 -
254.254.254.1
```

The key here is that I need to search quickly over the IP addresses and have them take the smallest surface area in the database, with the smallest overhead. 
I thought about compressing the file to gzip and that is also an option, I need to file to be the smallest as it can get, while still having good performance on the hash lookups, I need to search the IP address via the hash value not the IP address value.....

Comment: Another possibility is to store the IP addresses in a binary format, which only requires 4 bytes per address rather than the 15 (if using `Char`), 17 (if using `VarChar`), 30 (if using `NChar`) or 32 (if using `NVarChar`). This also allows you to search more quickly through the database (even more so than using character fields).

Comment: Can you post all the data-types for those fields? I might be able to help you cut down on the overhead for them.